# Using Youtube Standalone player in app in Android

Tags: android, firebase, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am using **Youtube API** in my application and want to use Youtube **standAlone player** in it, but I am not getting how to implement it in my application as I am using **Firebase as a database**. I have gone through many forums and Youtube standAlone player documentation but it did not make any useful help, please help.

> I am using Android Studio

**Firebase Adapter class file:**

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <post, postViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post, postViewHolder>(

            post.class,
            R.layout.post_row_recycle_home,
            postViewHolder.class,
            mDatabaseReference
    ){
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(postViewHolder viewHolder, post model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setYoutube(model.getYoutube());             
    };
       mrecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

      public static class postViewHolder extends RecyclerViewPager.ViewHolder{

      View mView;

      public postViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

   public void setYoutube(final String youtube){
            final YouTubePlayerView youPlay = (YouTubePlayerView) mView.findViewById(R.id.youtuber);
            youPlay.initialize("SOME KEY",
                    new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                            YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

                            youTubePlayer.cueVideo(youtube);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                            YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                        }
                    });
        }
```

Comment: This [sample app](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/) shows how to use a [`YouTubeStandalonePlayer`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeStandalonePlayer) intent to start a standalone YouTube player in a separate activity. This player can either be fullscreen or it can appear as a dialog above the current activity. You may also check this [related thread](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-play-videos-through-YouTube%E2%80%99s-standalone-player-in-Android-using-YouTube%E2%80%99s-API) for more information.

Comment: I think my question was unclear, i wanted to add youtube standalone player with firebase. These links does not provide useful info for my case.